# Knowing how much to receive when getting data from server

Tags: c, sockets, modulo

I'm learning socket programming for C, and I've got the server and client talking and sending messages without any issues, but I need a way for the client to know how many bytes it's supposed to receive. Part of the assignment is to make a header, which includes a checksum, which should be the binary form of number_of_bytes_sent % 32. I've got the server making and sending the header just fine, but I'm a bit stumped as to how I can get the number of bytes I'm supposed to receive from that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buffer on both sides (emission and reception). And you need to have and follow some *convention* on how requests and replies are organized. At the application level, your protocol should know where a reply or a request (more generally any application message) is starting and ending. Study for examples [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Remember that TCP sockets are just streams of bytes *without message boundaries*.

So the client might successfully `send` a single message of one fragment of a kilobyte, and the server could `recv`  two fragments of 512 bytes each. The converse could happen too. And the fragmentation is random so not reproducible.

Routers -notably Wifi ones- can (and do) fragment TCP/IP packets (and even sometimes defragment by concatenating them).

Libraries like [0mq](http://zeromq.org/) could help (and they are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can and probably should study their source code). Look also into HTTP libraries ([libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) on client side, [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) on server side).

If you implement some socket thing yourself, read [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) (and [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)).

> I'm a bit stumped as to how I can get the number of bytes I'm supposed to receive

Probably you are asked to define your application protocol. Then you could put the message (or content) length in your application header. The `Content-length:` attribute in [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) could be inspirational.